# Creating multiple documents from one during aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I've a collection with documents like following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f797a8f03b66b73edd4f56f"),
    "totalCounts" : 2300,
    "roadId" : "road_2",
    "type" : "CALL",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-01-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "counts" : {
        "GOOD" : 0.652173913043478,
        "BAD" : 0.347826086956522
    }
}
```

I want to do an aggregation that will create two separate documents (based on GOOD and BAD counts accordingly) from each one of the above. Is it possible or aggregation isn't what I need to use?

I need to produce something like this from each input document:

```
{
    "totalCounts" : 2300,
    "roadId" : "road_2",
    "type" : "CALL",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-01-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "state": "GOOD",
    "rank": 0.652173913043478
}

{
    "totalCounts" : 2300,
    "roadId" : "road_2",
    "type" : "CALL",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-01-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "state": "BAD",
    "rank": 0.347826086956522
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like following

```
[
  {
    $set: {
      counts: {
        $objectToArray: "$counts"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$counts"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      state: "$counts.k",
      rank: "$counts.v"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      counts: 0
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VnikpdlzTFC)**